# Rails 7 - choosing to render HTML or PDF depending on object field contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

My Rails 7 app contains an Article resource with a source field (string). It contains valid external URLs to blog articles - the index method returns a list of articles with a link_to method to each source.

I need to add a directory of pre-existing PDFs to Articles. They currently reside in /public/pdfs/ (can be moved elsewhere if desirable). Can I use the same "source" field to contain external URLs (https://...) and local static files (/public/pdfs/...)? Or do I need to populate another, pdf-only locator field in the resource?

All the PDFs already exist. No generation needed.

Any best practices appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to use the [Active Storage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) since it is a built in way to handle file attachments.

You don't say if the files are user input or server generated but I see these three scenarios:

**1. The file is a user input through a form**

This is the most covered use of Active storage and you will find many [tutorials](https://pragmaticstudio.com/tutorials/using-active-storage-in-rails)

**2. The file is server generated by the rails app**

Active Storage allows you to attach `IO` stream object therefore you can attach either the output of your generator (if returns `IO`) or a tempfile

```rb
def Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :pdf
end

Article.last.pdf.attach(io: File.open(filepath), filename: 'article.pdf', content_type: 'application/pdf')`
```

**3. The file is server generated by a different process**

In this scenario you need to find a way how to pass the file to the application. These are my ideas:

- wrap the software into some kind of a job so you can run it in your Rails application context
- implement HTTP API to upload the file to the application
- write a directory observer and attach new files in a directory to articles based on the filename (I think this is the most janky way but saved me once, so I decided to mention it)

Comment: Thanks. In this case the pdfs are created externally and uploaded by an admin to a directory. (No generation or form-based uploading required.)

Comment: I would create a form for the admin to upload the files in the web interface. Or if you insist on uploading the files to a directory then these files need to have some identifier that pairs them to the article (like ID in the name). Then you can either do the trick with directory observer or serve them directly from `/pdfs/#{article.id}.pdf` (if in still in `/public/pdfs`). The Active Storage processing has the advantage of mime type checking if the admin ever had malicious intentions.

Comment: Got it & will do. Appreciate it.